# Highlighting Text in VBA macro for Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, replace, highlight, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that will search the document and highlight every occurrence of a space, the word "for", and then another space like this " for " using modified code from this site, i have gotten this:

```
Sub findfunction()
If (findHL(ActiveDocument.Content, "[ for ]")) = True Then MsgBox "Highlight Comma's and Coordinating Conjunctions Done", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Highlight Result"
End Sub

Function findHL(r As Range, s As String) As Boolean
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
r.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
r.Find.Execute MatchWholeWord:=True, FindText:=s, MatchWildcards:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Format:=True, replacewith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
findHL = True
End Function
```

The problem is that it highlights every occurrence of just the letter f, o, and r. I want it to only highlight when the sequence " for " is found, not the individual characters. I am new to this, and I'm not sure where to go from here so any help would be appreciated. Thanks :D

Comment: check for [wildcards rules here](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are not necessery. Searching string should be " for " and MatchWildcards:=False.

```
Sub findfunction()
    If (findHL(ActiveDocument.Content, " for ")) = True Then
        MsgBox "Highlight Comma's and Coordinating Conjunctions Done", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Highlight Result"
    End If
End Sub

Function findHL(r As Range, s As String) As Boolean
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    r.Find.replacement.Highlight = True
    r.Find.Execute MatchWholeWord:=True, FindText:=s, MatchWildcards:=False, Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Format:=True, replacewith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    findHL = True
End Function
```